# SimpleXML and xpath getting a node's value

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have the following notes.xml XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And this PHP script

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('notes.xml');
    $result = $xml->xpath('//to');
    print_r($result);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result;
?>
```

Then, why the output is the following? (THERE IS NOT TOVE VALUE)

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
Array
```

Comment: From: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//to');
```

This will return you an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects, since there may be more than one `<to>` tag in your XML. In order to extract the text, you should use

```
echo (string) $result[0];
```

Casting to a string returns the text content from the tag.

If your XML is always that simple, you can also use

```
$result = (string) $xml->to;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [the manual for the `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). It always returns an array of zero or more `SimpleXMLElement` objects.

If you `echo` an array - any array at all - you get the word `Array`.

If you `echo` a `SimpleXMLElement` object, it will be automatically cast to string (as though you'd written `echo (string)$foo` in place of `echo $foo`, as shown in [the basic SimpleXML examples](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

So you need to look *inside* the array, to get the `SimpleXMLElement` object, and echo that. Remember that if no matches are found, the array will be empty.